# how can i generate a migration using TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync as the DataSource?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, migration, nestjs-typeorm

Trying to integrate migrations in a nest.js project I ran the migration:create command from typeorm and there was no problem, but when I try to generate a migration with migration:generate like this:   `yarn run typeorm migration:generate ./src/migrations -d ./src/database/database.provider.ts`
being ./src/migrations the folder where I want the migrations to be and ./src/database/database.provider.ts where I have my Datasource as I will show you in a moment, the point is that I got the following error:
`

```
Error: Given data source file must contain export of a DataSource instance
    at Function.loadDataSource (C:\Proyectos\AmazingDigisignBackend\documents-service-nest\node_modules\src\commands\CommandUtils.ts:49:19)
    at async Object.handler (C:\Proyectos\AmazingDigisignBackend\documents-service-nest\node_modules\src\commands\MigrationGenerateCommand.ts:73:26)
Done in 3.74s.
```

this is database.provider.ts:

```
import {DynamicModule} from "@nestjs/common";
import {ConfigService} from "@nestjs/config";
import {TypeOrmModule} from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import {DataSourceOptions} from "typeorm";

export const DatabaseProvider: DynamicModule = TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  inject: [ConfigService],
  async useFactory(config: ConfigService) {
    return {
      type: 'postgres',
      host: config.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
      username: config.get('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
      password: config.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
      port: config.get('DATABASE_PORT'),
      database: config.get('DATABASE_NAME'),
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: false,
      migrations: [__dirname + '/../src/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
    } as DataSourceOptions;
  }
})
```

and this is my database module:

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {DatabaseProvider} from './database.provider';

@Module({
  imports: [DatabaseProvider],
  exports: [DatabaseProvider]
})
export class DatabaseModule {
};
```

I have tried to use the old typeorm commands like:`yarn run typeorm migration:generate -n newMigration` .
I have checked the documentation like a hundred times and nowhere do they tell you how to generate a migration using the typeormmoduleconfig as datasource, I was thinking of creating an ormconfig.json but I don't like it, if nothing else works I guess I wouldn't have much choice.

Answer (score 0):

The file `database.provider.ts` that you are providing to the command `yarn run typeorm migration:generate` exports a NestJS dynamic module, not a DataSource that can be used by the TypeORM CLI.

However, you could add a function that build the DataSource options in `database.provider.ts`, and then reuse this function in a separate file to build the CLI's required configuration.

In your database.provider.ts :

```
import {DynamicModule} from "@nestjs/common";
import {ConfigService} from "@nestjs/config";
import {TypeOrmModule} from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import {DataSourceOptions} from "typeorm";

export const DatabaseProvider: DynamicModule = TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: buildDataSourceOptions
})

export function buildDataSourceOptions(configService: ConfigService): DataSourceOptions {
    return {
      type: 'postgres',
      host: config.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
      username: config.get('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
      password: config.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
      port: config.get('DATABASE_PORT'),
      database: config.get('DATABASE_NAME'),
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: false,
      migrations: [__dirname + '/../src/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
    };
}
```

and the configuration file for TypeORM cli, in a separate file (`database.config.ts` for example)

```js
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { buildDataSourceOptions } from './database.provider';

// This will load environment values.
ConfigModule.forRoot(/* Pass here the same options that you would pass when
calling this method from your root module */);

// This will be used by the cli
export default new DataSource(buildDataSourceOptions(new ConfigService()));
```

Therefore, you could call the CLI this way :

`yarn run typeorm migration:generate ./src/migrations -d ./src/database/database.config.ts`

Also, the option `autoLoadEntities` is not supported by the TypeORM CLI. You could replace this option by something like this `entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}']`